# Passing std::memory_order as constexpr differs from when it is not constexpr

Tags: c++, multithreading

This is a question regarding std::memory_order.

I have created the following two functions which are to be run on separate threads.

```
constexpr std::memory_order order = std::memory_order_relaxed;

void write()  // writer thread
{   
    x.store(true, order);
    y.store(true, order); 
}

void read()   // reader thread
{
    while (!y.load(order)) {}
    assert(x.load(order)); 
}
```

On an Arm host, the assert can fire, as the memory order I pass in the store and load methods are std::memory_order_relaxed. However, if I strip the "constexpr" off, the assert will never fire.

It seems to me that the value of the std::memory_order of the *store* and *load* methods must be determined in compile-time. If it is deferred to run-time, however, the behaviour will be undefiend.

Am I correct? If that is true, is there any C++ documentation emphasizing this limitation?

Answer (score 2):

`constexpr` doesn't matter. The assertion can (but doesn't need to) fail in either case. You are just getting lucky.

There is no undefined behavior if the order is not a compile-time constant.

Possibly (although impossible to tell without seeing generated assembly) is that the compiler wasn't able to determine that the value of `order` is a compile-time constant without the `constexpr` and so didn't apply some optimization/transformation based on that.

Answer (score 1):

As user17732522 says, it is perfectly legal for the `memory_order` to not be a constant, and the behavior is well defined.  There is nowhere in the standard that says it must be a constant.

I am guessing you are using gcc as your compiler.  It appears that with gcc specifically, when the `memory_order` argument is not a compile-time constant, it simply ignores the argument and emits an unconditional `seq_cst` operation.  This is certainly legal; it is always safe to provide stronger ordering than you requested.  They probably think that the performance difference between `seq_cst` and a potentially weaker order is small, and not worth the cost of a sequence of tests and branches to select different instructions at runtime.

(Hopefully it goes without saying that you should not rely on this behavior!  If you only request `relaxed` ordering, your code had better be correct in the event you actually get relaxed ordering.)

[Try on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/hWTYbobhe).  With gcc, on all the architectures I tested, the function `unknown()` has identical assembly code to `cst()`, which is different from `rel()` (relaxed store).

Testing a couple other compilers:

- icc: emits `seq_cst` unconditionally
- icx: test and branch
- clang: test and branch